# Switch statement with patterns

Tags: c#, .net-core

I use Visual Studio Code and after the release of VS 2017 I've just installed the Net Core Tools 1.1.1 hoping to implement the new C# 7 pattern matching feature like the one in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) example from MSFT:

```
switch(shape)
{
    case Circle c:
        WriteLine($"circle with radius {c.Radius}");
        break;
    case Rectangle s when (s.Length == s.Height):
        WriteLine($"{s.Length} x {s.Height} square");
        break;
    case Rectangle r:
        WriteLine($"{r.Length} x {r.Height} rectangle");
        break;
    default:
        WriteLine("<unknown shape>");
        break;
    case null:
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shape));
}
```

I have to implement a Switch statement with patterns to replace a long sequence of `if-then-else`:

```
var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("XYZ");
var propertyType = Type.GetType(property.PropertyType.FullName);

switch (propertyType)
{
    case Boolean b:
        writeLine("Convert a string to a Boolean");
        break;

     case Int32 i:
        WriteLine("Convert a string to a Int32");
        break;

     default:
        WriteLine("unknown type, skip");
        break;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following errors:

*'An expression of type Type cannot be handled by a pattern of type bool. [efcore]'*

*'An expression of type Type cannot be handled by a pattern of type int. [efcore]'*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to switch on the *value*, not on the *type* of the value:

```
var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("XYZ");
var value = property.GetValue(obj);

switch (value)
{
    case Boolean b:
        ...
    ...
}
```